# Add line between errorbar in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Context**

I used ggplot to draw a grouped error bar graph. I want to connect the points with lines within each group.

I tried to use geom_line(), but the result is not what I want.

**Question**

Is there any way to connect the points within each group with a line, like the red line in the figure below.

**Reproducible Code**

```
dat_a = structure(list(exposure = c("HDL", "HDL", "HDL", "HDL", "HDL", 
"HDL", "HDL", "HDL", "HDL"), event = c("mRS", "mRS", "mRS", "mRS", 
"mRS", "mRS", "mRS", "mRS", "mRS"), model = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("low", "middle", "high"
), class = "factor"), group = c("middle", "low", "high", "middle", 
"low", "high", "middle", "low", "high"), margin = c(0.292, 0.372, 
0.349, 0.25, 0.336, 0.281, 0.252, 0.35, 0.278), LL = c(0.273, 
0.327, 0.308, 0.23, 0.287, 0.235, 0.226, 0.285, 0.22), UL = c(0.311, 
0.417, 0.391, 0.27, 0.385, 0.326, 0.278, 0.415, 0.336)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

pd = position_dodge(.7)

ggplot(dat_a, aes(colour=group, y=margin, x=model, group=group))+
  geom_point(position=pd,shape=16,size=4)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = UL, ymin=LL), position=pd,width=0.2,size=1.1)+
  labs(title = "", x="", y="Marginal probability of poor prognosis") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="HDL cholesterol level"))+
  scale_color_jama()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title =element_text(size=14),axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),legend.title = element_text(size=12),
        legend.position = 'right')+ ylim(0.2,0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dodging and lines is always a bit tricky. The issue is that on the one hand we want the lines to be grouped by `model` but on the other hand we want them to be grouped by `group` for the dodging. TBMK there is no way to achieve that via dodging and the `group` aes. Instead I would go for manual dodging which requires to compute the `x` positions for the `geom_line` manually. To this end convert your `model` and `group` columns to numerics first. Second, rescale the `group_num` to a range of -1 to 1. This resealed column will be used to "shift" the points for each category of `model`.   Third, compute the amount of the shift which is simply the width used for dodging divided by the number of `group`s:

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)

dw <- .7
dw_line <- dw / length(unique(dat_a$group))
pd <- position_dodge(width)

dat_a$model_num <- as.numeric(factor(dat_a$model))
dat_a$group_num <- as.numeric(factor(dat_a$group))
dat_a$group_num <- scales::rescale(dat_a$group_num, to = c(-1, 1))

ggplot(dat_a, aes(colour = group, y = margin, x = model, group = group)) +
  geom_point(position = pd, shape = 16, size = 4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = UL, ymin = LL), position = pd, width = 0.2, size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = model_num + dw_line * group_num, group = model), color = "red", size = 2) +
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = "Marginal probability of poor prognosis") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "HDL cholesterol level")) +
  scale_color_jama() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12), legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.position = "right"
  ) +
  ylim(0.2, 0.5)
```